# Why is a Jordan region after rotating is still a Jordan region?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Given a Jordan region $E\subseteq \Bbb R^n$. My teacher said that if you rotate $E$ with some degree, the resulting new set $E'$ is still a Jordan region. The hint teacher gave is that "rotation" is a homeomorphism, and *a homeomorphism perserves the property of boundary*. PS: My teacher haven't taught change of variable formula yet, so a proof via this formula is not allowable.

However, I can't find out what does it mean. I know the related theorems of homeomorphisms, but can't recall one theorem said that how homeomorphism affects on *boundary* of a set. Also, I guess that my teacher perhaps means that $\partial E$ is measure zero, then $\partial E'$ is also measure zero, but I don't know whether it's valid, and why. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a homeomorphism, $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, and $p\in\partial E$, then $f(p)\in\partial f(E)$. That's because$$p\in\overline E\cap\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus E}=\delta E\implies f(p)\in\overline{f(E)}\cap\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus f(E)}=\partial f(E).$$

Comment: Hmm.. but why $\partial f(E)$ is measure zero?

Comment: That was your guess of what your teacher perhaps meant, but that guess is not correct.